# Storing weekly and monthly aggregates in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle9i

I need to dynamically update weekly and monthly sales data per product and customer. These need to be updated and checked during the sale of a product, and for various reasons I'm not able to use stored procedures or materialized views for this (I'll read everything into the application, modify everything in memory and then update and commit the results).

What is the best table structure for holding the sales during a period?

- Store the period type (M, W) with start and end dates, or just the type and start date?
- Use date fields and a char, or code it into a string ('M201201' / 'W201248')
- Normalize sales and periods into two tables, or keep both sales and the period in a single table?

I will be doing two kinds of queries - select the sales of the current weekly (xor monthly) period/customer/article but not update them, and select for update weekly and monthly periods for a customer/article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store both the start and end dates of the applicable period in the row, then your retrieval queries will be much easier, at least the ones that are based on a single date (like today).  This is a very typical mode of access since you are probably going to be looking at things from the perspective of a business transaction (like a specific sale) which happens on a given date.

It is very direct and simple to say `where @date_of_interest >= start_date and @date_of_interest <= end_date`.  Any other combination requires you to do date arithmetic either in code before you go to your query or within your query itself.

Keeping a type code (M, W) as well as both start and end dates entails introducing some redundancy.  However, you might choose to introduce this redundancy for the sake of easing data retrieval.  This: `where @date_of_interest >= start_date and @date_of_interest <= end_date and range_type='M'` is also very direct and simple.

As with all denormalization, you need to ensure that you have controls that will manage this redundancy.

Comment: Thanks, good point about the date arithmetic - that was my initial concern too. Unfortunately, I won't be able to avoid it because I have to put the correct date in when creating the entry - I can't simply use TRUNC(@date_of_interest,'IW') because of our ORM framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a normalized schema for that purpose where you store weekly and monthly aggregation in two different tables with the same structure. I don't know the kind of queries you're going to do, but I suppose that this would make it easier to do any sort of search (when it's done in the right way!!!).

Probably something like this sample

```
product_prices (
    prod_code,
    price,
    date_price_begin
);

sales (
    prod_code,
    customer_code,
    sale_date
);


<aggregate-week>
select trunc(sale_date,'w') as week,
    prod_code,
    customer_code,
    sum(price) keep (dense_rank first order by date_price_start) as price
from sales 
    natural join product_prices
where sale_date > date_from
group by trunc(sale_date,'iw'),
    prod_code,
    customer_code
/

<aggregate-month>
select trunc(sale_date,'m') as month,
    prod_code,
    customer_code,
    sum(price) keep (dense_rank first order by date_price_start) as price
from sales 
    natural join product_prices
where sale_date > date_from
group by trunc(sale_date,'m'),
    prod_code,
    customer_code
/
```

Comment: I can't do actual sql aggregation, I tried it once (using a view), and it just wasn't fast enough (I have to check the aggregated sales data for every order line). Also, I'm interested in the actual number of pieces sold during the whole period, not in the price first from the period. What are the benefits of using two tables, instead of one table with an index, or even a single table with two partitions?

Comment: I can't imagine how those query can be slow!! The tables they use would not be so big (with less than 50 bytes for each row) and the aggregation tables may be built incrementally (by adding new rows at every week/month end). Anyway I'll test the case and I will update my post with the results.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I don't need a weekly aggregate after the week has ended, I need it during the week (as a part of stock keeping). That means that when I'm processing a sale for product 123456 for customer 100000, on Wednesday 13:45, I need the total sales for the article from monday 00:00 until the start of the transaction on Wednesday. If every time I want to sell a product to a customer I have to do a 'SELECT .. GROUP BY' on the sales data, the database just won't be able to keep up. This is why I have to do an incremental update of the aggregate after each sale.